# How to change a specific value of a specific key in text file using python

Tags: python, key-value

I would like to know how to replace a value of a specific key in a text file using python

I have this text file named `passenger.txt` have the following:

```
{'Civil ID':'1', 'Name':'Mike', 'DOB':'12/2/2000', 'Gender':'Male', 'Customs fine':'', 'Status':''}
```

I want to replace `Status` value to `Sometext` instead of blank, I already have a code but it replacing the key not the value. So, I'm wondering how to change the value not the key.

Here is the code:

```py
passenger_db = "passenger.txt"
with open(passenger_db, "r+") as file:
  for single_line in f:
     x = single_line.replace('Status', 'Sometext')
     file.write(x)
```

I expect some one will help me.

Comment: do you have any other text in the file or does it always contains above data?

Comment: No, it contains another data same as the above data. Each one in a line. But every one has a different value.

Comment: Added another example to my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lines = []
with open('passenger.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        passenger = eval(line)

        # If you wish to update only certain strings
        if passenger['Civil ID'] == '1':
            passenger['Status'] = 'New status'

        lines.append(str(passenger))

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(f'{line}\n')
```

**Explanation:**

I'm afraid the only option for you is the following:

1. Read the whole file
2. Convert each line to a python object
3. Replace a key in the object
4. Convert it back to a sting
5. Write the result to the file again

Comment: But this will change the whole data if there is any another data in the file

Comment: Yes. If you wish to apply the change to a certain passenger only, you can add 'if' statement in the loop. if passenger['Civil ID'] == 1: ...

Comment: Is there is any another way? I don't want to make an file I need the change in the same file.
Even if we change the key-value pairs into any another way like `Key, value`

Comment: You can specify the same name of the file: on read and on write. I think there are no other ways. Even if you edit some file in a text editor it rewrites the whole file data on save.

Comment: Ok. And now how I can update a specific line for example if the `Civil ID = 1`?

Comment: I just updated the code with example of this case.

Comment: Yes it make sense to me, but it doesn't change any values :(

Comment: Ok. I tried to use `ast.literal_eval` and now it's work thanks bro.

Comment: Yes, or you can just compare with string: if passenger['Civil ID'] == '1'. I have updated the code above :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yaml` module to parse each line to a dictionary then you can just update the value with key name

```
import yaml

with open('passenger.txt') as fp, open('output.txt', 'w') as fw:
  for line in fp:
    data = yaml.safe_load(line)
    data['Status'] = 'Some text'
    fw.write(str(data) + '\n')
```

But it's better to use json file with list of objects
so you don't need to parse each line

Answer (score 0):

### Use RegEx substitution

If you don't feel like loading each line of data in Python dict object and modify the value (which is a totally fine way to do it), using RegEx would be a good alternative.

Regular expression is a very powerful tool when it comes to searching or manipulating string contents.

For the input txt file:

```
{'Civil ID':'1', 'Name':'Mike', 'DOB':'12/2/2000', 'Gender':'Male', 'Customs fine':'', 'Status':''}
{'Civil ID':'2', 'Name':'John', 'DOB':'12/2/2000', 'Gender':'Male', 'Customs fine':'', 'Status':'foo'}
{'Civil ID':'3', 'Name':'Mary', 'DOB':'12/2/2000', 'Gender':'Female', 'Customs fine':'', 'Status':'bar'}
```

```
import re


def set_values(filename: str, key: str, value: str):
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = f.read()
    updated_text = re.sub(f"(?<='{key}':').*(?='}})", value, text)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(updated_text)


set_values('passenger.txt', 'Status', 'Sometext')
```

The script with replace all occurrences of the `'Status':'<any-text>'` pattern with `Sometext`.

Result:

```
{'Civil ID':'1', 'Name':'Mike', 'DOB':'12/2/2000', 'Gender':'Male', 'Customs fine':'', 'Status':'Sometext'}
{'Civil ID':'2', 'Name':'John', 'DOB':'12/2/2000', 'Gender':'Male', 'Customs fine':'', 'Status':'Sometext'}
{'Civil ID':'3', 'Name':'Mary', 'DOB':'12/2/2000', 'Gender':'Female', 'Customs fine':'', 'Status':'Sometext'}
```

If you only want to modify one line instead of the whole file, just loop over the lines after reading the file and find the line you want to modify, then apply the regular expression substitution.

You can also tweak the RegEx pattern based on your need to substitute other content in the text file.

Comment: Yes I already want to modify one line. So can you please tell me where exactly I can adding the loop?

Comment: So you only want to modify one of the 'Status': '' pattern, despite this pattern shows up multiple times in the file? Does your file look like my example? If not, I need to know what it looks like and how do you distinguish the target line from other lines, except for the 'Status' key.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use JSON or pickle. But if you must:

```py
import ast, pathlib
passenger_db = Path("passenger.txt")
data = ast.literal_eval(passenger_db.read_text())
data['Status'] = 'SomeText'
passenger_db.write_text(str(data))
```

Comment: This way it works, but it's creating a new line with the new `Status` vaue